# White blank screen using webview

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to start an activity with webview layout, without opening up a new webbrowser. So it would be embeded in the app.

Seems like it worked for a few days and now... I'm only getting a white blank screen. Could you please give me a hand here?

Here's my xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/backBtn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:height="50dip"
    android:background="#4d867f"
    android:text="Back"
    android:textColor="#f9f9f9"
    android:textSize="20dip" />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's how I am calling the activity:

```
promotionBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PromotionActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("url", "https://www.test.com/apppromotion.html");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

And finally the activity:

```
package br.com.test.androidtools;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;




public class PromotionActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;
private Button backBtn;

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
    {
        Intent it = new Intent(PromotionActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity((Intent)it);

        return true;

    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.promotion_layout);

    backBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backBtn);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    webView.loadUrl(bundle.getString("url"));

    webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());

    backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent it = new Intent(PromotionActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity((Intent)it);
        }
    });



}




public class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}

}
```

Any ideas of what could fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: to debug this, before webView.loadUrl(bundle.getString("url"));, print the url using Log.d("test", "url = " + bundle.getString("url")); Is it set correctly there? Also, check your log for any warnings your WebView might print.

Comment: Hi Frank! It is getting the correct url...

Comment: But I also get this error: "E/chromium: [ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(313)] [.Parent-Compositor-0xe2f17b00]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url target had its SSL "Lets Encrypt" incorrectly configured.
So simple, but it took me a while to find out! So before looking for a hard to crack solution, just point webviewer to another url.

Answer (score 0):

**Change**

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
webView.loadUrl(bundle.getString("url"));
```

**To**

```
webView.loadUrl(getIntent().getStringExtra("url"));
```

**Note**

If you use `Bundle`,the next Activity can use `Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();` .

**Edit**

- Add permission in your manifest .

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  ```
- Add setting

  ```
  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  ```
- Make sure that `https://www.test.com/apppromotion.html` can load normally .

**Edit**

Make sure that the back button can display in the screen .

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/webView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/backBtn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:height="50dip"
            android:background="#4d867f"
            android:text="Back"
            android:textColor="#f9f9f9"
            android:textSize="20dip" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit**

You can try this .

```
<WebView 
    android:id="@+id/web_view" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layerType="hardware"/>
```

You can use `android:layerType` in the xml code .

Comment: Hi KeLiuyyue! Tried it but seems like I have to change a few extra things around.. right? It didn't work... I also tried the next code but still the same:

Comment: String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        webView.loadUrl(url);